# Using glDatePicker (or similar) into modal Boostrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've a simple page that requires 2 date input and I would use a datepicker to get them.
I've found glDatePicker http://glad.github.io/glDatePicker (thanks a lot!) that is simple, light and works very well.
My problem is use it in modal with bootstrap 3.
I can call function to display the datepicker, for example

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#date').glDatePicker();
});
```

and it works perfectly anywhere, except in modal where it look likes to appear behind the modal and/or it's not entirely shown (malformed).

I've alredy tried to put it in a specific div (like the author suggest), but the result is the same.

I think that it can't be attached correctly to the input field because of modal, but I'm not sure and anyway I don't know how to solve it :)

Thanks!

Comment: Please add more code, or better create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: All code is listed inside library, I cannot post all... I've a modal, with a simple input field (text), when I click on it, the above simple function should call glDatePicker() who provide the calendar just under the field text. It works nice in a normal page, but not in modal...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with another library. The fact is that the calendar that is shown is attached to "body" element and for this reason it cannot be seen in the modal popup. For this reason you can try if changing z-index property or positioning for you is enough. Otherwise (like in my case) was hacking the library in order to accept one additional optional parameter that was meant to store the dom element to attach the calendar to.

Comment: I've already try to change z-index value, it doesn't solve the problem.
Maybe because the calendar isnt' just covered by modal, but it's attached somewhere.. sometimes it appears on the upper left corner but very small; other times it shows but only a small fragment.

I didn't understand your second solution, how can I store the dom and pass it like an additional parameter?

My english is not the best one, I hope you can understand what I wrote :)
Thanks!

Comment: if you look at the code here: https://github.com/glad/glDatePicker/blob/master/glDatePicker.js#L332 you will see that the new HTML element is attached to the body and that is why it stays below your popup. The trick here is to customize the library in order to parametrize the dom element (for example in your case you can try attaching it to your modal)